# SharePoint Designer 2007 : Remove seconds fields from the email

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-workflow, datetime

The email notification sent out by the SharePoint Designer 2007 workflows includes seconds for the date/time field.
For example "This is a confirmation that you are registered to attend a DEMO at 10:00:00 AM".

How can I remove the seconds field from the email message.

The SharePoint List with date/time field displays fine (without the seconds)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

One option - you could create a calculated column to show a formatted version of your date and include that column in your email.

For example if you've got a field called "My Date" then you can create a calculated column called "My Formatted Date" (or whatever makes sense) using the following formula.

```
=TEXT([My Date]","mmm yyyy")
```

will display the date in a format like Jul 2011

```
=TEXT([My Date]","dd/mm/yyyy")
```

Will show 21/7/2011.